# How can I make sure two simultaneous pl/sql transactions wait on each other or are aware of the other

Tags: oracle, plsql, parallel-processing, simultaneous

I have a package that awaits a response from a service.  It is processing addresses for a user, of which there could be between one and three for a given order.  I am needing to perform some logic based on two criteria:

1. The service returns the success response
2. The success response has come back for all involved records.

Since this is asynchronous, it is possible I will be getting an order with 3 records, all being processed at the same time.  Each return record will result in a column in a row on a table being updated, and once the final record has been processed, I also update a 'READY TO IMPORT' column.  So currently, my logic checks to see if all the expected columns have been updated for every record it processes.  The idea being that as each record updates it's own column, on each check of another record, I will see that all required columns have been updated, meaning all records have been processed, and then I can update that final 'READY TO IMPORT' column.

I am finding that some sets of records are still happening at basically the same time, and so they are each looking for the other records column to be updated, finding it is not, and so the 'READY TO IMPORT' column never gets updated, even after all the records have been processed. Or at least that is my best theory based on what logging tells me.

I AM NOT doing a commit immediately after each record updates its assigned column currently - so I am wondering if adding a commit immediately after the update to the table might help.

So I am looking at options in addition to that as well.  I can come up with some, such as adding a wait to specific records so it is more likely it will always be the last processed, or to adding a clean up process that looks for cases where all necessary columns are updated, but there is no 'READY TO IMPORT' update, and updates it accordingly (basically a fallback when this issue occurs)

But I have to think there is a built in way to do this.  We are on Oracle 12c.  I have been looking at concurrent commits, but it is not clear to me if this is a good or advisable solution from reading the documentation.

Here is what the logic looks like, if it helps:

```
// code to update relevant column on order_table
...
//check if all columns have been updated on each instance of the logic running
IF all_oracle_ids_resolved(v_header_id, v_destination_contact_id) THEN
   v_debug_progress := v_debug_progress || 'START UPDATE ORDER_TABLE TO READY TO IMPORT' || CHR(13);
   UPDATE order_table
      SET order_status = 'READY TO IMPORT',
          up_last_updated_by = -2,
          up_last_update_date = SYSTIMESTAMP
    WHERE header_id = v_header_id; 
END IF;
```

and the FUNCTION it calls:

```
FUNCTION all_oracle_ids_resolved(p_header_id              NUMBER,
                                 --send in p_destination_contact_id to identify whether or not a destiantion address exists on the order
                                 p_destination_contact_id VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN IS

   v_dummy_cnt NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN

   SELECT count(*)
     INTO v_dummy_cnt
     FROM ORDER_TABLE
    WHERE header_id = p_header_id
      --check that all head address Oracle data exists
      AND (head_customer_id IS NOT NULL AND head_contact_id IS NOT NULL)
      --check that all ship address Oracle data exists
      AND (ship_customer_id IS NOT NULL AND ship_contact_id IS NOT NULL AND ship_site_use_id IS NOT NULL)
      --check that all bill address Oracle data exists
      AND (bill_customer_id IS NOT NULL AND bill_contact_id IS NOT NULL AND bill_site_use_id IS NOT NULL)
      --check that all dest address Oracle data exists, unless there is no destination address to verify
      AND ((dest_customer_id IS NOT NULL AND dest_contact_id IS NOT NULL AND dest_site_use_id IS NOT NULL) OR (p_destination_contact_id IS NULL));

   IF v_dummy_cnt > 0 THEN
      RETURN TRUE;
   ELSE
      RETURN FALSE;
   END IF;

END all_oracle_ids_resolved;
```

My expectation is that the update to order_table will only occur when all records have been processed.  How can I accomplish this when there are between 1-3 asynchronous transactions that need to be accounted for?

Comment: look at "select .. for update"

Comment: @OldProgrammer thanks for the suggestion. I have looked into this, and let me see if I can summarize the intention here. I would use SELECT .. FOR UPDATE to lock the order_table as each record being processed causes it to be updated. That way, if simultaneous transactions occur, one will be blocked by the other. The blocked one will hit a deadlock exception, at which point I can do something like sleep for 10 seconds and then try again, since the locking update should now be complete. Is that about right? I have coded this, but I am having trouble generating simultaneous calls to test it

Comment: Yeah if you want the select to return immediately if the row is locked, you need to add "NOWAIT" to the statement, and handle the exception as you said. It is not a deadlock.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I think I understand, but let me clarify. I would add NO WAIT to my SELECT .. FOR UPDATE - something like SELECT .. FOR UPDATE NO WAIT;.  Then I catch the ORA-00054 exception.  Could I even use something like NO WAIT 15 to give the second execution a built in 15 seconds buffer?  If I am understanding this, then the ORA-00054 should almost never happen since we are talking sub-second executions

Comment: Yes that is correct.  There is no option to specify a wait time.

Comment: @OldProgrammeris there not a wait time option?  I am basing that on reading here - http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_for_update_nowait.htm - am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: Oh, one other question too - the SELECT .. FOR UPDATE and the table updates are all happening to a table over a DB Link.  Is this going to introduce any other problems?

Comment: I think the doc I linked in my recent comment about NOWAIT has an error - NOWAIT has no time option, I think the document might have meant to indicate WAIT

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using SELECT .. FOR UPDATE as suggested in comment replies to original post